# What did Lila truly want from Dexter?

Tags: character, dexter

She never seemed to be one of those 'settle down' type of people, to melt and to cook babies type.

She didn't go to the Police after Doakes told her the truth about Dexter being the Bay Harbor Butcher! *She wanted to save Dexter*..

She could have demanded any money from the Miami Police in exchange of truth about Dexter! *She was not interested in money* either..

Angel could give her all the s*x she ever wanted,
*She wasn't interested in that either*..

Did she want to marry Dexter to clear her immigrant status and become a citizen?

**What was her true game plan?**

Comment: *to melt and to cook babies type.* Do what now?

Comment: @phantom42 - Presumably supposed to be something like "the make babies and cook dinner type", or "the barefoot and pregnant type", or some such. Not that Dexter would have been more compatible with her is she was the type to melt and cook babies - that's not *his* style at all.

Answer (score 7):

She seemed to connect with Dexter, as in her mind she felt that Dexter is the same as her, "killer" and "wild".

Although it was not true, Dexter was a killer but was not wild or a person with no motivation or plan, every action that Dexter took had some planning or motivation.

But she ignored all those facts, and she also tried to free Dexter from all his rules and make him like herself, but eventually failed to do so.

Comment: I agree with this mostly--I think she was looking for someone *she thought could convert to her ways. Lila is nice offshoot/evolution from Brian, since both characters are somewhat manic, play pyschological games, and are seeking to make Dexter their own. Sometimes there are people that just happen to latch onto other people that they deem worthy of mass manipulation---With Dexter (series) there are a lot of characters that we don't really get full backgrounds on, so it's hard to pipoint long term motives and/or play "what if scenarios" with, by only seeing short-term dynamics.

Comment: I'd go beyond "convert to her ways", and add "and control". I think her *being* in charge (even if it didn't *seem* like she was in charge) was critical with her. Dexter showing independence was, in her eyes, a bad thing.